# How to set class member as constant?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

In the code below, I have declared `string name` in class `SHAPE` so that the sub-classes can have a constant name.

But, the g++ compiler gives the error inside `CIRCLE` class that `'name' does not name a type`.

```
class SHAPE
{
    protected:
    string name;
};

class CIRCLE : public SHAPE
{
    name = "circle";
    public:
    void display()
    {
        cout<<name;
    }
};
```

I am new to OOP and C++.
Any help in correcting and improving my code will be appreciated.

Comment: Read about [member initialization lists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to create a class contructor

```
class CIRCLE : public SHAPE
{

public:
    CIRCLE() {
        name="circle";
    }
    void display()
    {
        cout<<name;
    }
};
```

Comment: Syntactically valid code might help.

Comment: That does the work. Could you add some comment in the code for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You need constructors for non-static classes if you want to be able to run them.

I'd suggest something like this:

```
class SHAPE
{
    protected:
    SHAPE(const string& name_) : name(name_) {}  //Sets the string name.
    const string name;
};

class CIRCLE : public SHAPE
{
    public:
    CIRCLE() : SHAPE("TheNameYouWant") {}  //Call parents constructor
    void display()
    {
        cout<<name;
    }
};
```

So now you call it like this:

```
CIRCLE c1("someName");
c1.display();
```

It will still be impossible to create a SHAPE object, meaning that this won't work (if that is what you want):

```
SHAPE s1("someName");
```

Comment: You should pass strings by const reference.

Comment: @mtijn Yeah, I did. Also used "new" wrong ^^ too much C# and too little c++ lately. Dont know if the code will run since I cant testrun it atm.

Comment: You can use ideone.com

Comment: What is a "non-static class"? What is a "static class"?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit static classes are classes that you don't have to create an object of before running. So they don't have a constructor and only have static variables and methods.

Comment: I want object of class `CIRCLE` to have `name = circle` automatically, instead of passing name as parameter

Comment: @Barun Then just hardcore it like this: `CIRCLE() : SHAPE("theNameYouWant") {}`. I edited the code example to show what I mean

Answer (score 0):

```
class SHAPE
{
public:
    explicit SHAPE(const string& name)
    : name(name)
    {
    }

    const string& GetName() const
    {
        return name;
    }

protected:
    string name;
};

class CIRCLE : public SHAPE
{
public:
    explicit CIRCLE(const string& name)
    : SHAPE(name)
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    CIRCLE c("circle1");
    cout << c.GetName() << "\n";
}
```

Comment: I don't see how a code dump without explanation is helpful for this guy. Poor way to teach.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That's why internet tutorials were invented. He can compile it, step through the code, look up what he doesn't understand. At least I give some good practices for him to see.

Comment: Internet tutorials can kiss me. He should be learning from a good book. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: Honestly, I didn't get anything from this.

Comment: @Barun Then learn until you do. Only you can make yourself a good programmer!